# If element is visible do something to another element. Jquery

Tags: jquery, element, exists, visible

I have multiple containers like this

```
<div class="container">
    <span>
     <!-- Inside the span is either text or img -->
    </span>
</div>
```

Goal is to have border around ".container span" only if it contains and image.

i tried something like this.. but it doesnt work

```
if( $(this).find('.container span img').is(":visible") ){ $(".container span").css({'border':'10px'}); }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.css('border','10px');`?

Comment: @Nick I think it works either way

Comment: check out my answer for the link to a working demo. Your border will not show up unless you specify a type of border along with size. If you do not specify a color, black will be used.

Comment: @David Hedlund @Hussein I added something from both of your codes and it worked for me 

http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/8/

@David Hedlund your code on its own was good but for some reason it just didnt work with my generated code..

Comment: did my code not work for you.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visible` is a pseudo selector so it's

```
.is(':visible')
```

You can also use it like so

```
$(this).find('.container span img:visible')
```

**EDIT**

Hey, wait, are you saying that it might not *contain* an image at all? In that case, you don't want to be checking for visibility, but rather something like

```
$(this).find('.container span img').length > 0
```

(of course, if there *might* be images, and they *might* be hidden, you want to check the length of `img:visible`)

---

**EDIT 2**

Now you've got a working check as to whether or not there is a visible image. The rest depends on your implementation. I assumed from the use of `$(this)` that there will be a DOM node of some kind to search within, that'll only have one `.container` for each value of `this`.

If that's not the case - if you want to look at *all* of the DOM in one go - you could go about something like this:

```
$('.container span img:visible').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('span').css('border', '10px');
});
```

Above, you're saying that "for all visible images inside a span inside a `.container`, add a border to their parent spans.

Another way of doing it would be something like this:

```
$('.container span').filter(function() { return $(this).find('img:visible').length > 0; }).css('border', '10px');
```

Comment: @David Hedlund oh yea..  my bad i wrote it wrong in the example. Correct or not it doesnt work. http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/

Comment: Alright, thanks for the jsfiddle, that sorted out the issue for me. See my update

Comment: @David Hedlund im not sure i know how to use that.. http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/4/ im pretty sure i dont.

Comment: @Shababoo: Well, the jsfiddle lacks context. The way it is right now `this` is the entire DOM. Your current if statement says, "is there an image inside a span, inside an element with the class container, anywhere in the document?" And there is. And since it is, you proceed to give the span inside *all* `.content` elements a border.

Comment: @David Hedlund thats what i was trying to avoid with "(this).find" :D so that only those specific span's that have img inside them will have a border.. are you saying it cant be done?

Comment: @David Hedlund now it uuhm gives border to every span that doesnt have image inside.. but it should be the other way around.. did i do something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/6/

Comment: @Shababoo: well, now your javascript is starting to shape up, but there are still issues. What's happening here is that you have a CSS style that sets up *all* spans to have a default border. For the spans with images, you're then setting the *entire* `border` property (not just `border-width`) to `10px`, which means they lose their `border-style: solid`. So this *removes* the border from the spans with images. To see what's going on, change `10px` to `10px solid`, for instance.

Comment: @Shababoo: so what you want to fix here is to set it up so that by default, the spans don't have border. You need to remove `border-style: solid` from your CSS. Why? Because `border-width` and `border-color` both have default values, so as soon as you set a border style, you're adding a border. The css `border` property is a composite object for setting all of those three properties in one go, so you're actually overriding whatever's there, anyway. For your images, set `.css('border', '10px solid black');`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. First, your css is wrong. Your telling it to give it a 10px border of nothing. You need to specify what *kind* of border and probably the color.

Second, `.is("visible")` should be `.is(":visible")`

Check out the working code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/6Arer/)

(I had to remove the `this` selector but you can modify your existing code to the above.)

Comment: i determined the solidness of border in css file so.. its ok..

Point is that there are spans that dont have images and then theres spans that do have images.. and only the ones that have images in them should get this border around them.. your code sumbles in to the same problem mine does.. everything gets border.. image or no image..

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.container').find('span').find('img').parents('span:first').css('boder','10px solid red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/1/

Comment: im not sure what that accomplishes except prevents the first span from getting a border.. http://jsfiddle.net/VMAJ7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have the `span`. You can apply the border directly to the image without the need for a span tag, specially if you are loading your images dynamically and your images have different dimensions. You then have to ensure your span tag is resized to match your image width and height. You can simplify things by getting rid of the `span` tag, else if all your images have same dimensions, you need to specify your span width and height. Also don't forget to specify your border properties such as style and color.

```
var $cont = $('.container span');
var $cont1 = $('.container span img');
$cont.each(function() {
    $cont.has('img').css({
        'width': $cont1.width(),
        'height': $cont1.height(),
        'border': '10px solid red'
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/GnXv4/6/

Comment: yea the span is needed.. and if i didnt need it.. i could just make that with css.. img { border: 10px solid; }

Comment: Check updated link above. I also wrote the code so span tag get's it's height and width from the image.

Comment: it seems like it still runs to the same problem i had.. it kinda ignores the request of showing border around only those spans that have image in them.. http://jsfiddle.net/GnXv4/3/

Comment: @shababoo Check updated code at http://jsfiddle.net/GnXv4/6. We need to use has() function to check for img tags and each() to loop thru the spans. I updated the post.